# Exportar dados do MySQL para arquivo CSV em formato UTF-8

Tags: csv, mysql

Estou utilizado a ferramenta `Workbench` para acessar dados do meu banco de dados MySQL, porém quando tento exportar os dados retornados para um arquivo ***.CSV** não estou conseguindo exportar o mesmo no formato **UTF-8**, porém se exporto para qualquer outro formato de arquivo **(XML, JSON, etc)** todos os dados são exibidos corretamente. É possível gerar um arquivo *.CSV no formato UTF-8 quando exportamos o resultado de uma `Query` no `Workbench`?

Apenas para complemento, a configuração do banco esta assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se não me engano pelo resultado da query ele exporta de acordo com a colação do banco, mas não tenho certeza.

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860086/mysql-workbench-charset

Comment: @AnthraxisBR, quando tu diz `colação do banco` quer dizer o formato original que o collation é salvo?

Comment: @Fox.11 eu segui as instrução do link que tu sugeriu porém o meu já esta com o collarion configurado para UTF-8